# Ansible msg: "winrm or requests is not installed: cannot import name certs"

Tags: python, ansible, winrm

I'm trying to use Ansible's win_ping module to ping a Windows host from a Linux control machine.

Problem:
I run the following command from the same directory as the "hosts" file and run into "winrm or requests is not installed: cannot import name certs" error.

```
$> ansible win -i ./hosts -m win_ping
dev-app1 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: cannot import name certs"
}
```

Definition within "hosts":

```
[win]
dev-app1 ansible_host=10.123.456.78

[win:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_password=adminspassword
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Versions of everything installed on my Linux machine: 
* ansible 2.7.2 
* python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] 
* Winrm: python2-winrm-0.3.0-1.el7.noarch 
* Requests: 
python-requests-2.6.0-1.el7_1.noarch 
python2-requests_ntlm-1.1.0-1.el7.noarch

Any idea what's causing the error? Could it be due to version incompatibility or any other missing modules?

Thanks!

Comment: I would strongly advise trying without so many rpms, since they quite often don't get the dependency tree correct. Create a virtualenv, `pip install ansible==2.7 pywinrm` and then try with that virtualenv's ansible. Separately, you seem to have failed to specify [`ansible_winrm_transport`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#authentication-options)

Answer (score 2):

This is failing even if python2-winrm version 0.3.0 is already installed via yum. 
**Reason**: yum doesn't installs all dependent module for winrm. Use python package manager (pip) instead.

```
thinkred1cartoon:$ ansible all -i hosts.txt -m win_ping
172.16.96.135 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: cannot import name certs"
```

Find exact winrm package installed -

```
yum list installed | grep winrm
python2-winrm.noarch              0.3.0-1.el7                @epel
```

Run next 2 commands -

```
1)    yum autoremove python2-winrm.noarch   #uninstalls python2-winrm.noarch along with all its dependencies

2)    pip install "pywinrm>=0.3.0"          # Installs pywinrm using pip.
```

[More detail here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html)

Then ping: pong worked just fine over https, port=5986

```
ram@thinkred1cartoon$ ansible all -i hosts.txt -m win_ping
172.16.96.135 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

A quick peek into my ansible inventory:

```
ram@thinkred1cartoon$ cat hosts.txt           

[win]
172.16.96.135

[win:vars]
ansible_user='Raman'
ansible_password='XXXXX'
#ansible_port=5985
ansible_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
#ansible_winrm_scheme=http
ansible_winrm_scheme=https
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Conversely, if you can't/don't want to run command 1, then command 2 won't work for you. 
In that case, run command 3 only.

```
3 ) pip install --ignore-installed "pywinrm>=0.3.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I have a lot of python's versions installed what I did is to check with which of them my ansible was built:

```
[myuser@hostname ~]$ head -1 `which ansible`
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
```

Then I ran pip install for that particular version of Ansible:

```
[myuser@hostname ~]$ sudo pip3.8 install pywinrm
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3.8 install --user` instead.\
Collecting pywinrm
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1a/74bdbb7a3f8a6c1d2254c39c53c2d388529a314366130147d180522c59a3/pywinrm-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pywinrm) (1.12.0)
Collecting xmltodict
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/db/fd0326e331726f07ff7f40675cd86aa804bfd2e5016c727fa761c934990e/xmltodict-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests>=2.9.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting requests-ntlm>=1.1.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/4b/8b9a1afde8072c4d5710d9fa91433d504325821b038e00237dc8d6d833dc/requests_ntlm-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/de/5be2e3eed8426f871b170663333a0f627fc2924cc386cd41be065e7ea870/urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/34/cd29f4dd8a23ce45f2b8ce9631ff2d4205fb74eddb412a3dc4fd1e4aa800/certifi-2022.9.14-py3-none-any.whl (162kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 2.1MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->pywinrm) (2.8)
Collecting charset-normalizer<3,>=2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/51/a507c856293ab05cdc1db77ff4bc1268ddd39f29e7dc4919aa497f0adbec/charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.3 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->pywinrm) (2.8)
Collecting ntlm-auth>=1.0.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/84/97c550164b54942b0e908c31ef09d9469f3ba4cd7332a671e2125732f63b/ntlm_auth-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->pywinrm) (1.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->pywinrm) (2.19)
Installing collected packages: xmltodict, urllib3, certifi, charset-normalizer, requests, ntlm-auth, requests-ntlm, pywinrm
  WARNING: The script normalizer is installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed certifi-2022.9.14 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 ntlm-auth-1.5.0 pywinrm-0.4.3 requests-2.28.1 requests-ntlm-1.1.0 urllib3-1.26.12 xmltodict-0.13.0
```

And this fixed my issue about:

```
X.X.X.X | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'"
}
```

Now is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @fesm788m is the correct one. I also encountered same issue recently after performing yum update.

After some checking, it appears ansible updated its python version to 3.11

So, I ran as follows:

```
$ head -1 `which ansible`
#!/usr/bin/python3.11

$ sudo yum install python3.11-pip python3.11-winrm
```

And done, it works again now :)